# swift - parsing JSON from API with Decodable

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, parsing

I am getting data from api using URLSession, then parsing received JSON with Decodable structs. But catching an error decoding JSON. Maybe I missed something in the structs or in decoding. Please advice.

JSON output from request url:
[image]

Structs:

```
struct Responce: Decodable {
    var source: String
    var user: String
    var media_sources: [MediaSourses]
}

struct MediaSourses: Decodable {
    var source: String
    var media_source: String
    var key: MediaSource
    var sub1: MediaSource
    var sub2: MediaSource
    var sub3: MediaSource
}

struct MediaSource: Decodable {
    var name: String
    var split: Bool
    var delimiter: String
    var position: Int
}
```

Code:

```
class HTTPRequester {
    
    func getData (url: URL, completion: @escaping(Responce?) -> Void) {
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {data, _, _ in
            
            guard let jsonData = data else {
                print("Error getting jsonData")
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Responce.self, from: jsonData)
                print(decodedData)
                completion(decodedData)
            }
            catch {
                print("Error decoding json")
                completion(nil)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Getting error:
[image]

Comment: Instead of printing a meaningless literal string "Error decoding json" print the `error` instance. It tells you exactly what's wrong

Comment: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "delimiter", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "media_sources", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "sub2", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"delimiter\", intValue: nil) (\"delimiter\").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: The error is clear. Please look at the JSON. In `sub2` and `sub3` there is no key `delimiter` and `position`. Declare `delimiter` as `String?` and `position` as `Int?`

Comment: Editing the question and fixing the issue makes the question pointless and confusing for others. Please either reverse the editing or delete the question

Comment: I got this - valueNotFound(__lldb_expr_5.MediaSourses, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "media_sources", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "Expected MediaSourses but found null instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: The error message doesn't match the JSON. The error says that the first item in the array `media_sources` is `nil`.

Comment: It works.Thank you! I made source in MediaSources optional - var source: String? and furthermore created new struct Media for sub2 and sub3 with two properties in it.